# Extract room measurements from text

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract room measurements from text data but cant see to find a way that will meet all possibilities.

Sample Data:

```
room_info <- c(
  "Lounge (3.66m x 3.66m (12'0\" x 12'0\"))",
  "Dining Kitchen (4.39m x 3.66m (14'5 x 12'0\"))",
  "Bedroom One (3.73m x 3.73m (12'3\" x 12'3\"))",
  "Bedroom Two (3.53m x 1.98m (11'7\" x 6'6\"))",
  "Shower Room (2.06m x 1.52m (6'9\" x 5'0\"))",
  "Occasional Loft Room (4.04m x 3.78m (13'3\" x 12'5\"))",
  "En-Suite Bathroom (3.18m x 1.98m (10'5\" x 6'6\"))"
  )

###Desired Output:

room_measurements <- tibble(
  meas_1 = c(3.66, 4.39, 3.73, 3.53, 2.06, 4.04, 3.18), 
  meas_2 = c(3.66, 3.66, 3.73, 1.98, 1.52, 3.78, 1.98)
)
```

I have put the below together which works for some but not all with the last values incorrect. For some reason a `-` appears before the data throwing off the `substr`.

I'm reasonably confident the measurements won't go over 9.99m and therefore shouldn't be longer than 4 total characters in length.

```
room_info %>% 
  gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", .) %>%
  as_tibble() %>% mutate(
  meas_1 = as.numeric(substr(value, 1,4)),
  meas_2 = as.numeric(substr(value, 5,8)),
) %>% select(-1) 

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  meas_1 meas_2
   <dbl>  <dbl>
1   3.66   3.66
2   4.39   3.66
3   3.73   3.73
4   3.53   1.98
5   2.06   1.52
6   4.04   3.78
7  -3.1   81.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your current solution, you just need to capture the first two float numbers in the string and just match the rest, and replace with backreferences to the two groups:

```r
sub(".*?(\\d+\\.\\d+).*?(\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1\\2", .)
```

See [**the regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2d9YZM/1). *Details*:

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `(\d+\.\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits, dot, one or more digits
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `(\d+\.\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits, dot, one or more digits
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as many as possible.

The full R method call will look like

```r
room_info %>% 
  sub(".*?(\\d+\\.\\d+).*?(\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1\\2", .) %>%
  as_tibble() %>% mutate(
  meas_1 = as.numeric(substr(value, 1,4)),
  meas_2 = as.numeric(substr(value, 5,8)),
) %>% select(-1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  meas_1 meas_2
   <dbl>  <dbl>
1   3.66   3.66
2   4.39   3.66
3   3.73   3.73
4   3.53   1.98
5   2.06   1.52
6   4.04   3.78
7   3.18   1.98
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract` with regex lookaround to extract the substring that are numeric after the `(` or after the `x and space

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(text = room_info) %>% 
    transmute(meas_1 = str_extract(text, "(?<=\\()[0-9.]+"), 
              meas_2 = str_extract(text, "(?<=x )[0-9.]+")) %>%
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#  meas_1 meas_2
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1   3.66   3.66
#2   4.39   3.66
#3   3.73   3.73
#4   3.53   1.98
#5   2.06   1.52
#6   4.04   3.78
#7   3.18   1.98
```

---

Or using `read.table` from `base R` after extracting substring from the data

```
read.table(text = gsub("[a-z]", "", sub(".*\\((.*)\\s*\\(.*", 
   "\\1", room_info)), header = FALSE, col.names = c('meas_1', 'meas_2'))
```

-output

```
#   meas_1 meas_2
#1   3.66   3.66
#2   4.39   3.66
#3   3.73   3.73
#4   3.53   1.98
#5   2.06   1.52
#6   4.04   3.78
#7   3.18   1.98
```

---

In the OP's post, the last value showed `-` because in `gsub`, it is removing all characters except the digits (`0-9` or `.` or `-`) and the `-` is from `En-Suite`